# preg_match and remove character

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string like

```
https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xta1\/v\/t1.0-9\/p50x50\/11139440_1010664825611559_1305796970308877058_n.jpg?oh=6da07776dd8ba8270c2c32de2957b7d3&oe=560D0AF0
```

I want to replace all "\" with preg_replace function 
to be like this

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xta1/v/t1.0-9/p50x50/11139440_1010664825611559_1305796970308877058_n.jpg?oh=6da07776dd8ba8270c2c32de2957b7d3&oe=560D0AF0
```

Examples:

- https:**//** -> https:**//**
- net/hphotos-xta1/  -> net/hphotos-xta1/

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Why is it necessary to use regexp? Is [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use either, when stripslashes() will do this for you:

**result:**

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xta1/v/t1.0-9/p50x50/11139440_1010664825611559_1305796970308877058_n.jpg?oh=6da07776dd8ba8270c2c32de2957b7d3&oe=560D0AF0
```

**example**

```
<?php
$string = 'https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xta1\/v\/t1.0-9\/p50x50\/11139440_1010664825611559_1305796970308877058_n.jpg?oh=6da07776dd8ba8270c2c32de2957b7d3&oe=560D0AF0';

echo stripslashes($string);
```